# Error installing Jupyter on Windows 10 using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to Stack Overflow, so please forgive me for any errors.

I am trying to install Jupyter on my Windows 10 machine using command prompt. I have already installed Python(3.8.0).

I receive the following error at the end:

**The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.**

The installation starts, download the necessary file but suddenly there's a long list of error with the above message at the end. I have tried running command prompt as administrator but that also fails.
I have tried executing following commands for installation but nothing works:

```
> pip install jupyter

> python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
  python3 -m pip install jupyter

> pip install jupyterlab
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? And how do I solve it?

Thank You!

Comment: Why don't you just install Anaconda from their website?

Comment: Anaconda currently doesn't support python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

I am on Windows 10, and using Pyhton 3.8. Running first

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

and then

```
pip install notebook
```

worked for me quite well. Thanks to [@roberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481867/roberto)

Check the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917629/encountered-an-error-while-installing-jupyter-notebook-using-pip)

Comment: Works fine on Python 3.8.1 x64 for me as well - although this could depend if MS build tools etc. are installed on the system.